# Pre render event for Layout pages in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

How to write pre-render event for asp.net mvc?
Actually my issue is that I need to make document standards of my webpage in IE10 to
IE9+ standards because by default it is IE7+ standards and my application is not working as per the requirement due to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> How to write pre-render event for asp.net mvc?

You can create a simple ActionFilter - [Reference taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094742/capturing-html-output-with-a-controller-action-filter)

```
    public class UpdateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private HtmlTextWriter tw;
        private StringWriter sw;
        private StringBuilder sb;
        private HttpWriter output;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            output = (HttpWriter)filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Output;
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Output = tw;
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            string response = sb.ToString();
            output.Write(response);
        }
    }
```

And when you request a page, you can customize your response html in `OnResultExecuted()`. When you put a breakpoint, it is going to be like this -

[image]