# Render content of css stylesheets as inline-style attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

I have the same question as this guy: ["Compile" CSS into HTML as inline styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894081/compile-css-into-html-as-inline-styles)

Except that I use asp.net mvc razor or to be more correct RazorEngine: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

I compile .cshtml files into html files. While I do this or after this process is done I want that all .css files and their id`s, tags, classes and their properties/values are rendered as inline styles directly into the html tag as style attribute.

I need to use style attributes because the result html is a template to be shown in email clients like gmail/outlook/mobile etc...

How would you start with the process of converting the css stylesheet definitions into the appropriate style attributes?

Comment: Is this for sending out emails ?

Comment: emails allows <style> tag in the email body. There are some trouble but it still will work

Comment: @Yasser yes it is!

Comment: @teovankot No, gmail does not support style-tag in the header-tag. https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/gmail-no-head/ Or https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1

Comment: @Pascal than i gess you should just put all your styles in htmlAttributes object of razor HtmlHelpers

Comment: I assume that you will have to do it by hand, I'm not aware of any solution for this.

Comment: @RaulA. I found a solution which is exactly doing that: https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely MUST replace the class attribute on your HTML attributes with in-line style attributes, you are looking at a non-trivial task.  A good solution won't be a simple `String.Replace` or `Regex.Replace`.  Here is how I would probably approach it:

- Create a custom ActionFilter to read the HTML after your controller action executes ([Capturing HTML output with a controller action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094742/capturing-html-output-with-a-controller-action-filter))
- Load the HTML using something like [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- Load your CSS class using [a CSS parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512720/is-there-a-css-parser-for-c)
- Find the class attribute on your HTML elements, remove it, replace it with a style attribute, and set the style attribute value to the value of the corresponding CSS class (read using the CSS parser mentioned above).

Comment: Filter stuff I wont do, as I use RazorEngine that means I do not use a asp.net web project + iis server. Well as gmail does not support class attributes as they require an internal/external stylesheet, I have to do it that way when I want re-usable css definitions! Thanks for the htmlagilitypack and css parser links. I think thats the way to go.

Comment: I found a solution which is already doing the HTMLAgilityPack + CSS parser and combine them together!!! see https://github.com/milkshakesoftware/PreMailer.Net